# What is the best way to dynamically increase a numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say we have an incoming stream of data of size (1,N), it is a numpy array

```
read_data = [[foo, foo_1, foo_2]]
```

And we want to do something with that or simply append it to a larger array.

```
data=np.vstack((data,real_data)) (or whatever method you choose)
```

My trouble usually comes in the fact that I do not know the dimensions of the incoming data, so what I sometimes do, is:

- I generate a buffer with the known dimensions and start populating it.
- I generate a first trash read, either empty or with zeros and just append over it, and then erase it.

In matlab this is very easy, since it dynamically creates the array you need as soon as you give data (although is not recommended to do)

What is the best way to do it in python?

Comment: Do you want to append the individual values of foo to data, or the entire array of foo?  If you want to just read in numpy arrays and add their values to data, maybe just increasing the size of data by one using something like `newsize = data.shape +1`, `data.resize(newsize)`, `data[newsize] = yourdata` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think a good option is:

```
import numpy
first_array = numpy.array([1,2,3])
new_array = numpy.append(first_array, [4,5,6])
print new_array
```

And the output is: 
[1 2 3 4 5 6]

Comment: this was my first thought also, but the only problem with this is that `numpy.append` creates a copy of the original array, and that becomes prohibitive with large arrays.  `resize` changes the original array in place, though.

Comment: @seth I doubt that that's guaranteed. If `resize` acts as `realloc`, then it might have to copy the array depending on the "fragmentation" of memory(and in that case it's *almost* the same as calling `append`).

Comment: numpy can only deal with arrays regularly spaced in memory. In general, there is no way of doing what you want without creating a new array each time. You could of course create a new array for each bit of incoming data and combine them only at the end, or periodically.